# Qt support for HockeySDK

Tags: qt, hockeyapp

Is there a way to use the [HockeySDK](http://hockeyapp.net/) within a Qt application? I made a basic test trying to import your framework into my project adding these lines to my profile:

```
# test.pro
LIBS += -F/Applications/HockeyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks -framework HockeySDK
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += hockey.m
```

With the following code:

```
// hockey.m
#include <HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h>

void hockey() {
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] configureWithIdentifier:@"APP_IDENTIFIER"];
    // Do some additional configuration if needed here
    [[BITHockeyManager sharedHockeyManager] startManager];
}
```

But I have the following error:

```
error: 'HockeySDK/HockeySDK.h' file not found
```

Any help?

Comment: Try to create a project with "HockeySDK" but without Qt. Or read the manuals, how to configure this SDK. Your problem is not related to Qt.

Comment: When adding the framework to my XCode project and the code (following the manual), it compiles fine. For Qt, I'm using Qt Creator.

Comment: I manage compile my project by 1) moving *.h files in HockeySDK.framework/Headers to a HockeySDK folder accessible by the include path 2) renaming the binary *HockeySDK* to *libhockey.a*

Comment: I found a simpler solution adding QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem using the following pro file:

```
# test.pro
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/path/to/the/folder/containing/frameworks
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -F/path/to/the/folder/containing/frameworks
LIBS += -F/path/to/the/folder/containing/frameworks
LIBS += -framework HockeySDK
LIBS += -framework Foundation

OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += hockey.m
```